# Preventing BASH chunk from being evaluated in RMarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

The chunk option `eval=F` works for R chunks, but not for for BASH chunks in Rmarkdown when I hit the `Run` button in RStudio (it works when I click the `Knit` button):

````
```{r eval=FALSE, engine='sh'}
echo This code is evaluated
```
>This code is evaluated
````

Other chunk options, as `include=F` will work.

How can I prevent a bash chunk from being evaluated in R Markdown when using the `Run` button in RStudio?

Comment: As also demonstrated by hrbrmstr's answer, I can't reproduce this (rmarkdown_1.10, R 3.5.1, Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: There is no error. The problem was that I was running the chunk by itself (from the *Run* button, instead of doing Knit. Anyways, is there anyway to prevent the chunk from running even if you try to force it? I want to prevent myself from executing critical chunks accidentally.

Comment: I don't know of any way to make the behavior of the Run button conditional on chunk options.

Comment: Aye @duckmayr, that's not even "a thing" for straight R code chunks.

Comment: So your question is specific to the RStudio IDE. Have you tried the latest preview version? https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Answer (score 1):

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{bash, eval=FALSE, engine="sh"}
echo "Don't Run Me"
```

```{bash, eval=TRUE, engine="sh"}
echo "Don't Run Me"
```
````

produces:

[image]